# Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated when compile flutter

Tags: flutter

when I am compile my flutter project on Fedora 32, it shows this error:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible
    // annotable parameter count: 3 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 3 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 2
   L0
   L1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 25 L2
    INVOKESTATIC kotlinx/coroutines/Dispatchers.getIO ()Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineDispatcher;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/coroutines/CoroutineContext
    NEW com/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml$compressedByteArray$2
    DUP
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    ALOAD 2
    ACONST_NULL
    INVOKESPECIAL com/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml$compressedByteArray$2.<init> (Lcom/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Ref$ObjectRef;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Ref$IntRef;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)V
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function2
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKESTATIC kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt.withContext (Lkotlin/coroutines/CoroutineContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   L3
    LINENUMBER 47 L3
    ARETURN
   L4
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml; L0 L4 0
    LOCALVARIABLE context Landroid/content/Context; L0 L4 1
    LOCALVARIABLE maxSize I L0 L4 2
    LOCALVARIABLE $completion Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation; L0 L4 3
    MAXSTACK = 7
    MAXLOCALS = 4

File being compiled at position: (25,5) in /home/dolphin/apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluwx-2.4.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIO.kt
The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.endVisit(FunctionCodegen.java:990)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:487)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:634)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node:
compressedByteArray (Landroid/content/Context;ILkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;:
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible
    // annotable parameter count: 3 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 3 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 2
   L0
   L1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 25 L2
    INVOKESTATIC kotlinx/coroutines/Dispatchers.getIO ()Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineDispatcher;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/coroutines/CoroutineContext
    NEW com/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml$compressedByteArray$2
    DUP
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    ALOAD 2
    ACONST_NULL
    INVOKESPECIAL com/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml$compressedByteArray$2.<init> (Lcom/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Ref$ObjectRef;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Ref$IntRef;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)V
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function2
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKESTATIC kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt.withContext (Lkotlin/coroutines/CoroutineContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   L3
    LINENUMBER 47 L3
    ARETURN
   L4
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml; L0 L4 0
    LOCALVARIABLE context Landroid/content/Context; L0 L4 1
    LOCALVARIABLE maxSize I L0 L4 2
    LOCALVARIABLE $completion Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation; L0 L4 3
    MAXSTACK = 7
    MAXLOCALS = 4

Element is unknownThe root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.endVisit(FunctionCodegen.java:983)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node:
compressedByteArray (Landroid/content/Context;ILkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;:
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible
    // annotable parameter count: 3 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 3 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 2
   L0
    LINENUMBER 25 L0
    INVOKESTATIC kotlinx/coroutines/Dispatchers.getIO ()Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineDispatcher;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/coroutines/CoroutineContext
    NEW com/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml$compressedByteArray$2
    DUP
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    ALOAD 2
    ACONST_NULL
    INVOKESPECIAL com/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml$compressedByteArray$2.<init> (Lcom/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Ref$ObjectRef;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Ref$IntRef;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)V
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function2
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKESTATIC kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt.withContext (Lkotlin/coroutines/CoroutineContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   L1
    LINENUMBER 47 L1
    ARETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/jarvan/fluwx/io/ImagesIOIml; L0 L2 0
    LOCALVARIABLE context Landroid/content/Context; L0 L2 1
    LOCALVARIABLE maxSize I L0 L2 2
    LOCALVARIABLE $completion Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation; L0 L2 3
    MAXSTACK = 7
    MAXLOCALS = 4

Element is unknownThe root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.MethodVerifier.transform(MethodVerifier.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:90)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: AFTER mandatory stack transformations: incorrect bytecode
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.MethodVerifier.transform(MethodVerifier.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.CompositeMethodTransformer.transform(CompositeMethodTransformer.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.OptimizationMethodVisitor.performTransformations(OptimizationMethodVisitor.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:70)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 8: Expected an object reference, but found I
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.MethodTransformer.runAnalyzer(MethodTransformer.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.MethodTransformer.analyze(MethodTransformer.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.MethodVerifier.transform(MethodVerifier.kt:26)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 8: Expected an object reference, but found I
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:291)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.MethodTransformer.runAnalyzer(MethodTransformer.java:31)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Expected an object reference, but found I
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.copyOperation(BasicVerifier.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.copyOperation(BasicVerifier.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.execute(Frame.java:288)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:187)
    ... 58 more
```

what should I do to fix this problem? in my Mac Book pro this code could successfully compile. this is the [source code](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-open.git).